# Sharing a Google Drive folder with a Google Group

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-drive-sharing

Can a Google drive folder be shared with a Google group? If yes, can each individual person in the group access the folder through their own personal email address? And if they are removed from the Google Group do they lose access?

Comment: I think at some point Google was pushing Google Sites and put some limitations on Groups, to try to force people to use Google Sites.  Not sure what the current status is.  I suggest you test it out by creating a test group with some test email addresses as members, and see whether each address can see the files in the Drive folder. You can also try kicking someone out and see what happens.  There used to be two ways of kicking someone out -- retaining access, and losing access.  Not sure of the current status.

Answer (score 1):

You can share a Google Drive folder with a Google group.
Need to share the folder at such address:

```
Groupname@googlegroups.com
```

Anyone who is removed from the group loses access!